# Why “being” instead of “be” for this sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Why “**being**” instead of “**be**” for this sentence

> Writing lyrics in Thai takes a long time for me for my band ... because we sometimes have a western melody and the Thai language, **being** tonal, sometimes doesn’t fit.

I have a feeling that “Being” is correct but I do not know why.

Comment: Is this sentence the answer to a question like, "Why do you write songs in English instead of in Thai?"

Comment: @gotube Yes, kind of.

Comment: Could you add the question? It changes the meaning of the answer. In fact, without a question before, this sentence isn't grammatical.

Comment: Below is the dialogue.               Q : In 2006, you also contributed to a benefit album for victims of the tsunami, right ?

A : That’s right

Q : So what was behind that ?

A : Mr.XXX got a bunch of like-minded musicians together to do a charity album and everybody had five days to submit songs for this record because he was going to bring it out quick.

Writing lyrics in Thai takes a long time for me for my band at the time because we sometimes have a western melody…………

Comment: The 2nd definition [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/being), showing the use of _being_ as a _link verb_, may be useful.

Comment: Yes, '...the Thai language, being tonal, doesn't fit' means the same as '...the Thai language, because it is tonal, doesn't fit'.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Please take a look at this link below. https://slideplayer.com/slide/6647401/ I wonder if my example sentence fall under the clause of no.7 as well?